# Database migration from SQL Server to Snowflake in Jitterbit Cloud Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jitterbit

Currently, I am trying to migrate tables from SQL Server to Snowflake in Jitterbit Cloud Studio.

For that, I would like to build a Jitterbit process with operations like this:

[Operation 1: Select all table names from SQL Server] {for each table name, call Operation 2} ->
[Operation 2: (Select the metadata of the table from SQL Server) -> (Generate create table SQL query for Snowflake) -> (Execute the create table SQL query)] ->
[Operation 3: (Select all data from the SQL Server table) -> (Insert into the Snowflake table)]

I am now trying to build Operation 3 which needs to execute a dynamic query to select fields from the SQL Server table and then insert into the Snowflake table using dynamic SQL. I need to use dynamic SQL because the fields I will select and insert depend on the table I am processing.

Could someone please give me any pointers on how to make this workflow dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to point you to:

1. Jitterbit supports several [database-related functions](https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/functions/database-functions/). These only apply to the generic Database connector, so they would be helpful for pulling the data out of the SQL tables. This list includes a function for calling a stored procedure.
2. The Database connector also allows for [manual queries](https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/connectors/database/database-query-activity/#databasequeryactivity-manual-query) if you prefer to use that. The text box where you enter the SQL statement can accept global variables.
3. The Snowflake connector also supports [invoking a stored procedure](https://success.jitterbit.com/cloud-studio/cloud-studio-reference/connectors/snowflake/invoke-stored-procedure-activity/), which is probably your best bet as the activities for inserting/updating require selecting a specific table.